# Configuring Android Steroids App to work with Facebook-Phonegap plugin

Tags: android, facebook, steroids

I would be extremely grateful if someone could walk me through the process of configuring my facebook app to accept connections from my android scanner build of my steroids app. Specific areas that I am not entirely clear on are:

1. Generating a keystore for my app
2. Hashing the keystore
3. Configuring the Android build settings
4. Configuring the facebook settings within Facebook. With specific attention to what Class Name / activity I want facebook to launch, and how to ensure my Class Name and package name are consistent with my Android build settings.

I've been fighting with this for a while, and can't help but feel as though I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have gone through the official documentation or not; but they have explained each steps that you've mentioned step by step: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Try for once (if not tried yet), and if you find any specific problems post your questions here (I don't think you'll find any after reading the doc)

Comment: I followed those steps. I am still unclear as to what my Class Name and package name should be since Appgyver is performing a cloud build. Questions 3 and 4 are really what I'm after here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.
I have used [Android Decompiler](http://www.decompileandroid.com/) to find the main class.

In my case it was: `com.appgyver.runtime.standalone.chromium.MainActivity`.

Looks pretty generic. Might work in your case too.